# mod_ssl.so failing to load after upgrade to Apache 2.4.27 - undefined symbol: SSL_get_srp_userinfo

Tags: apache, ssl

I'm trying to upgrade to Apache 2.4.27, from 2.4.26. The configure, make & make install all complete, but when I try to bounce Apache, I get the following:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 145 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so: undefined symbol: SSL_get_srp_userinfo
```

OpenSSL version is openssl-1.0.2l, installed by running:

```
./config --prefix=/usr/local/ --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl enable-tlsext shared
make && make install
```

Apache 2.4.27 was installed by running:

```
./configure --enable-modules=all --enable-ssl --with-included-apr --enable-mod-proxy --with-included-apr-util
make && make install
```

I've had the same problem several times before, and the answer was to make sure LD_LIBRARY_PATH was set to `/usr/local/lib64:/usr/local/lib` however that isn't helping this time. I've tried configuring & compiling with this set, and with no LD_LIBRARY_PATH, neither helped.

mod_ssl.so looks like it's getting compiled against the yum installed version of OpenSSL:

```
[root@localhost httpd-2.4.27]# yum list installed  |grep -i ssl
openssl.i686                     1.0.1e-57.el6             @ol6_latest
openssl.x86_64                   1.0.1e-57.el6             @ol6_latest
openssl-devel.x86_64             1.0.1e-57.el6             @ol6_latest
pyOpenSSL.x86_64                 0.13.1-2.el6              @ol6_latest

ldd /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd012ba000)
        libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f3258fb7000)
        libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f3258bd1000)
```

I've tried plenty of different options (way too many to list here), such as `--with-ssl=/usr/local/openssl, --enable-ssl=shared` as well as setting `LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib64"` in config.nice but still no joy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to solve this from a comment at https://serverfault.com/questions/587267/upgrade-to-apache-2-4-9-opensssl-error-ssl-get-srp-userinfo. Turns out setting LDFLAGS was the answer:

```
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib64"; export LDFLAGS
"./configure" \
"--enable-so" \
"--with-included-apr" \
"--enable-ssl" \
"--with-ssl=/usr/local/openssl" \
"LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib64" \
"$@"
```